# I get webhooks error even though I never used one in react

Tags: reactjs

Ive been trying to make a web through react, so I just created a folder with create-react-app.
But as soon as I seperate the components and routes folder and render it, I get the error.
Its really killing me.. I'd really appreciate someones help.[image: This is how Ive seperated it..][image: And react gives me webhook error.]
I didn't used any webhooks, I did match the version of react and react-dom, and Im pretty sure I have only one react here.

Comment: "you might have more than one copy of react in the same app." i see 2 node_modules and 2 package.json, something's not right.

Comment: @Adarsh Wow thanks.. Im new to react, and having a hard time how this things work. I've deleted all of the files and recreated it, and now it works! Thank you really :)